# Getting sqlresult into bash variable without oracle header/footer

Tags: sql, bash, sqlplus

```
#!/bin/bash -x

x=`sqlplus scott/tiger@xe<<endl
set heading off
select sysdate from dual;
exit
endl`

echo the answer is $x
```

is outputting

```
the answer is SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Mar 27 09:01:25 2013 Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved. Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production SQL> SQL> 27-MAR-13 SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Productiong
```

All I want is the result of the query sysdate.  How do I get rid of all the oracle relase, copyright, ... info.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
sqlplus -s
```

will then eliminate the headers

Comment: The parameter "-s" its only to connect to DB in silent mode.