# Set BASH variable based on SQL output

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, sqlplus

I need to set a BASH variable based on SQL output that gives an e-mail address. As a test I've done:

`email=$(echo "SELECT email FROM adr" | sqlplus $user/$pass@$db)`

An `echo $email` shows:

`SQL*Plus: Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production on Fri Oct 25 10:45:06 2013 (c) Copyright 2000 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved. Connected to: Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production JServer Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production SQL> 2 Disconnected from Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production JServer Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production`

So I guess I need some sort of trimming to just get the e-mail address?

A manual `SELECT` as follows shows the complete output:

```
SQL> SELECT email FROM adr;

EMAIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user@mail.com
```

What is the simplest way to grab the e-mail address?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663763/getting-sqlresult-into-bash-variable-without-oracle-header-footer?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use `-s` (silent mode). Also, turn off column headings and feedback as shown below:

```
email=$(sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db << EOF
set serveroutput on
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT email FROM adr;
exit;
EOF
)
```

Comment: Thanks but the e-mail address seems to have a line separator before it so it's breaking the script. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Use `tr` to remove the line break. Change the first line to: `email=$(sqlplus -s /nolog $user/$pass@$db << EOF | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what `/NOLOG` is for? That causes an error message but when it's removed it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need `/nolog`. It's only used if you do not want to provide a user/passwd on the command line and want sqlplus to prompt for it instead.